# Fetching a date from SqlServer 2008 in python

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to fetch a date from sqlserver2008 convert it into milliseconds and use it in my code.
This is my code

```
cursor.execute("select min (d.Date) from (select ProdID as brand ,max(Datekey) as Dt from SocMet_Daily_Fact where ProvID=5 group by ProdId) a left join dimdate d on a.Dt =d.DateKey")
    from_date=cursor.fetchone()
    print "printing from_date type"
    print str(type(from_date))
    from_date=parser.parse(from_date)
    print from_date
    from_sec=time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date, "%Y-%m-%d H:%M:%S").timetuple())
    from_sec=int(from_sec*1000)
    print from_sec
```

I get this response/error.

```
 printing from_date type
    <type 'pyodbc.Row'>
    'pyodbc.Row' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Is my parsing correct?Is this the correct type of parsing to convert a DB row object into a date type object?

Note that in the database the row is in this format

```
2014-07-01 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try giving `from_date[0]`. since your from date is sql queryresult  and min(date) is present first element

Comment: Used this line
from_sec=time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date[0], "%Y-%m-%d H:%M:%S").timetuple())

and I encountered this error:
printing from_date type
`<type 'pyodbc.Row'>
(datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 1, 0, 0), )
<type 'pyodbc.Row'>
must be string, not datetime.datetime`

Comment: @user1841772 try str(from_date[0])

Comment: Thank you.How stupid of me! not using str(from_date[0]).